# How to set array of objects as a marker in karate?

Tags: json, karate

I have file.json with content:

```
{
  "key": "#notnull",
  "value": {
    "id": "#notnull",
    "data": {
      "array": "marker <--"
    }
  }
}
```

What should I set instead of "marker" to use the file.json as a template for matching such kind of objects:

```
{
  "key": "1",
  "value": {
    "id": "1",
    "data": {
      "array": [
        {  
          "name": "Some name",
          "surname": "Some surname" 
        },
        {  
          "name": "Some name",
          "surname": "Some surname" 
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I need to do:

```
* def objectTemplate = read('path/to/file.json')
* match realObject == objectTemplate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Peter's answer and some investigation - here it is how it should be configured (not real json structure, just an example). So we have: 
  event.json:

```
{
  "key": "#notnull",
  "value": {
    "id": "#notnull",
    "data": {
      "persons": "#[] person"
    }
  }
}
```

person.json:

```
{
  "name": "#notnull",
  "surname": "#notnull"
}
```

and some-feature.feature:

```
Feature: some feature
  Background:
    # below variable name should be the same like in event.json persons field: "#[] person"
    * def person = read('classpath:test/person.json')
    * def eventTemplate = read('classpath:test/event.json')

    * def realEvent =
    """
      {
        "key": "1",
        "value": {
          "id": "1",
          "data": {
            "persons": [
              {
                "name": "MyName",
                "surname": "MySurname"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    """

  Scenario: some scenario
    # the sequence is important: eventTemplate == realEvent will not work
    * match realEvent == eventTemplate
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the docs for "embedded expressions" and schema validation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#schema-validation

This simple example should make it clear:

```
* def item = { foo: '#string' }
* def schema = { array: '#[] item' }
* def response = { array: [{ foo: 'bar1' }, { foo: 'bar2' }] }
* match response == schema
```

Comment: Hi, Peter! Thanks for your answer, it helped me to make configuration which I need.